# SQL Query Failing to Parse

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Please kindly assist with the code below. This is part of a report I am working on. The query uses an IF statement and has a nested IF to return the desired result. I get errors when parsing the query as shown below but I can't seem to resolve the errors.

**Query**

```
IF("GLAFS"."FSCSDSG"='A' AND "GLAFS"."FSCSYR">=(CONVERT('@GLYEAR@',SQL_NUMERIC) -4),IF
("GLAFS"."OPENBAL"=0 AND "GLAFS"."NETPERD1"=0 AND "GLAFS"."NETPERD2"=0 AND "GLAFS"."NETPERD3"=0 
AND "GLAFS"."NETPERD4"=0 AND "GLAFS"."NETPERD5"=0 AND "GLAFS"."NETPERD6"=0 
AND "GLAFS"."NETPERD7"=0 AND "GLAFS"."NETPERD8"=0 AND "GLAFS"."NETPERD9"=0 
AND "GLAFS"."NETPERD10"=0 AND "GLAFS"."NETPERD11"=0 AND "GLAFS"."NETPERD12"=0 
AND "GLAFS"."NETPERD13"=0,0,1),0)
```

**Errors**

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '@GLYEAR@'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near ','.
```

Comment: Is this how your format your SQL Code?  It seems nearly unreadable to me.  Why no indentations?

Comment: Is this from a SQL Statement or from a Stored Procedure or function or something?

Comment: Where did you generate this code from, @kaybee?  The IF (and that @GLYEAR@) are not set up to use SQL code, but appear to be from some other system.  Are you trying to convert the query from one type of RDBMS/query language to another?

Comment: Where did you get this?  The syntax is entirely wrong for Microsoft SQL Server.